How to postprocess pgfplotstable with siunitx
I would like to round the numbers in my table to two significant digits. This does not seem to be possible with pgfplots (at least Round to Significant Figures Not Decimal Places with PgfPlots has no answer). That is also why this is no duplicate of Postprocessing pgfplotstable results using siunitx
So I would like to use \num from siunitx. Something like the following example, but with num evaluated on the cell content. The {} of \add interfere with the {} of num. How do I properly escape this?
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableset{col sep = comma}

\begin{document} 

\pgfplotstableread{
test
0.824141
0.98035000000000005
1.85588
0.23383000000000001
}\runtimetable

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns={test},
    columns/test/.style={
        preproc/expr={1 / ##1},
        postproc cell content/.append style={
            /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={num\{}{\}}}
    },
]\runtimetable


\end{document}

